# NullReferenceException and I Don't Know Why

Tags: c#, .net, list, nullreferenceexception

I have two classes:

```
class Player
{
    public string Id { set; get; }
    public int yPos { set; get; }
    public List<Shot> shots;
    public Player(string _Id, int _yPos)
    {
        Id = _Id;
        yPos = _yPos;
    }

}
class Shot
{
    public int yPos { set; get; }
    public Shot(int _yPos)
    {
        yPos = _yPos;
    }
}
```

When  I try to put new Shot in list of shots for the player I get NullReferenceException:

```
Player pl = new Player("Nick",50);
pl.shots.Add(new Shot(pl.yPos)); // this line throws exception
```

Probably something ultimately simple.

Comment: pl.shots = new List<shot>(); pl.shots.Add(new Shot(pl.yPos));

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your `Player` constructor, just initialize `shots = new List<Shot>();`

Answer (score 1):

You need to new the shots in the Player constructor (or before you add to it).

```
shots = new List<Shot>();
```

Answer (score 0):

I like the below a bit better, only initialize shots if you need it and if you ever need to add logic to accessing Shots, you can without having to alter the use of Shots all over the place.

```
private List<Shot> _shots;

public List<Shot> Shots
{
    get 
    { 
        if (_shots == null) 
        {
            _shots = new List<Shot>();
        }
        return _shots;
    }
    set
    {
        _shots = value;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is not a good practice.  You should never initialize a property within itself.  It hides potential paths and can be real problematic when using with other classes.

Comment: I think you might need the `new List<Shot>()` in the `set` as well

Comment: @tsells - can you explain further about hiding potential paths?

Comment: @diaho - when you call myObject.Shots.Add(...) you are accessing Shots before you .Add to it, hence the get is called.

Comment: Properties are intended to act as place holders for objects.  They should never participate in the initialization of themselves.  In the example above the user would be better off using Auto Properties.  For example - am using a public API and I want to see if the Shots property is null - I have no way to tell.  As soon as I reference the property it creates a new instance.  if(Shots == null) will always be false.